# How to pass textBlock control to a Class

Tags: windows-phone-7

say I have a textBlock control  and I want to pass it to a class which controls the textBlock to display certain Message.

1)  When I call a method in the class, I want textBlock to show  message.  Example  " Checking connection...."

2) When the method complete the required task, the textBlock visibility become collapsed.

In the XAML : I have

a) textBlock name=textBlockMsg
b) a Button to call the class

Appreciate your help.

-- Update :

This class file inside project

```
public class  GeoCalculation
{

     public GeoCalculation()     {  }


  public void  CalculateDistance()
  {
        //- Begin -- want the textBlockMsg show  :  in progress......

       --code 

     //-- when end-----, textBlockMsg visibility becom collapse


   }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you named you `TextBox` in the `XAML` with `textBlockMsg`, this will work

**Edit**
// I will not implement the whole INotifyPropertyChanged check how to do to it : [implement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx)

```
public class CalculationClass : INotifyPropertyChanged    
{
      public void  CalculateDistance()
      {
       TextToBeBound = "in progress..."

       --code 

       VisibilityToBeBound = Collapsed;

      }
      public string TextToBeBound
      {  //... insert the implement of this property + NotifyPropertyChanged
        get {...} 
        set {...}
      }

      public Visibility VisibilityToBeBound
      {  //... insert the implement of this property + NotifyPropertyChanged
        get {...} 
        set {...}
      }

}
```

Then in the XAML add this :

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtBlocMsg"  Visibility={"Binding VisibilityToBeBound"}  Text={Binding TextToBeBound"}/>
```

Don't forget to set the `DataContext` of the UI to your class (in my case `CalculationClass`

You should be good to go. If all this was new. I recommend you read about data Binding + MVVM pattern.

**Edit**
It's bad practice to pass UI element to model/business classes. You should use the MVVM pattern.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. This class is Not Inside the Page object itself. This class is inside the Project as a class file.

Comment: Then you need to use a ViewModel that has a text property, you bind it to the Text Property of the textBlockMsg. Check my update code in 5 minutes :)

Comment: Thank again. I will follow the link. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem hope this helps. I added one comment : doesn't pass UI element to business class, it's not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can have a parameter to pass the TextBock:

   public void  CalculateDistance(TextBlock tb)
   {
       tb.Text = "in progress..."

   --code

   tb.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
   }
2. You coud use a the constructor of your class to inject the textblock it should handle

   public class GeoCalculation
   {
       private TextBlock _tb;

   ```
   public GeoCalculation(TextBlock tb)
   {
       _tb = tb;
   }

   public void  CalculateDistance()
   {
       _tb.Text = "in progress..."

      //code 

      _tb.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
   }
   ```

   }

A ViewModel and using DataBinding would be better by the way!
There you could use our class (method) to provice the text for the ui (textbox)

But be aware:
There is a .net way to do this. The GeoCoordinate class contains a method "GetDistanceTo" to calculate the distance between two geo points. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate.getdistanceto.aspx .

Comment: Thank for the reference link. In fact, I want to do more than calculate the distance such as bearing and other stuff. One question, will your method break if I do a loop of 32 frames per second, I mean will the textBlockMsg cause any problem if the logic do a 32 fps calculation . Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what u mean with a 32 fps calculation but if you want to a timeconsuming operation, you should use a background thread to not block the ui. After that thread finished you can change the visiblity of the textbox.